# Meteor: Most "Meteoric" way to clear form fields

Tags: meteor

I'm working on an example CRUD application with Meteor.js and am not sure how best to empty out the fields of a form. I need it in two places: when the Submit button is clicked, and when the Cancel button is clicked.

I implemented it this way by creating a utility function called clearFormFields() that just uses jQuery to empty their contents, but it doesn't feel as "Meteoric" as it should; I feel it should be scoped better so it doesn't have a global visibility. What am I doing wrong?

```
function clearFormFields() {
        $("#description").val("");
        $("#priority").val("");    
}

Template.todoNew.events({
    'click #cancel': function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        Session.set('editing', false);
        clearFormFields();
    },

    'submit form': function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var theDocument = {
            description: event.target.description.value,
            priority: event.target.priority.value               
        };
        if (Session.get("editing")) {
            Meteor.call("updateTodo", theDocument, Session.get('theDocumentId'))
        }
        else {
            Meteor.call("insertTodo", theDocument);            
        }        
        Session.set('editing', false);        
        clearFormFields();            
        /* Could do this twice but hate the code duplication.
        description: event.target.description.value = "";
        priority: event.target.priority.value = "";
        */
    }
});
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use the native reset method of the DOM form node ?

```
"submit form":function(event,template){
  event.preventDefault();
  // ...
  template.find("form").reset();
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_reset.asp

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks. Where does the lowercase template object come from? I didn't know about it.

Comment: Quoting http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/eventmaps "The handler function receives two arguments: event, an object with information about the event, and template, a template instance for the template where the handler is defined."

Comment: I totally missed that. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

The DOM object that originated the event can be accessed and reset from through event.target.reset();

```
"submit form":function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   //...
   event.target.reset();
}
```

http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/eventmaps