# Meteor Clear Form

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am trying to learn Meteor...and I starting to feel really frustrated.
My problem is really simple: I have a form (just one field), and after saving it I want to clean it so the user can add new data easly.
This is what I have:

```
  Template.nuevoEjercicio.events({
     'click #guardar': function (event, template) {

      var ejercicio = template.$("#ejercicio").val();

      ListaRutina.insert({
        rutina:"1",
        ejercicio:ejercicio,
        });

      // Clear form I am using the HTML template name here:
       template.find("nuevoEjercicio").reset();

      // Prevent default form submit
      return false;
    }
```

of course it doesn't work.
I have read this: [Meteor: Most "Meteoric" way to clear form fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27419653/meteor-most-meteoric-way-to-clear-form-fields)

What should I use to clean the form?
Thanks!

Comment: Not sure, but is `nuevoEjercicio` an `id`, like `template.find("#nuevoEjercicio")`? If that's a regular "selector" argument, `find("#nuevoEjercicio")` would seem to suggest you have a `nuevoEjercicio` element to reset, not a `form` element, which doesn't make sense (that would be a custom element type).

Answer (score 0):

ok I have found the problem. For the poor souls like me:

```
<Template name="nuevoEjercicio">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <form role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ejercicio" placeholder="Ejercicio">
    </div>
  </form>

    <button type="submit" class="btn .btn-success" id="guardar" >
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
    </button>
  </div>

</Template>
```

you don't need to call:

```
 template.find("nuevoEjercicio").reset();
```

but

```
 template.find("form").reset();
```

and add a

```
 <form role="form">
```

around your input fields.

Answer (score 0):

I had no choice but to create a DOM element in the page, generate a unique identifier and create a DOM based  tag to deal with submission.

Gross, but it doesn't happen often.